# Streamlit Aggrid Dynamic Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dynamic, ag-grid, streamlit

I am trying to combine streamlit , pandas and ag grid to display and adjust data in a dynamic way.When I edit the dataframe in the GUI (streamlit / aggrid) the C value doesn’t change in the GUI but if I just add an additional dataframe which is just a copy of it ...the value is updated (test below) .. I just want one dataframe with the possible to edit the column B in the grid and get instant result in col C.

```
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from st_aggrid import AgGrid, GridOptionsBuilder  #add import for GridOptionsBuilder

@st.cache_data()
def load_data():
    data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [0, 0, 0]]),columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
    return data
@st.cache_data()
def result(a,b):
    return a + b


data = load_data()

gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(data)
gb.configure_column('b',editable=True)
gridoptions = gb.build()
r = AgGrid(data, height=400,editable=True,gridOptions=gridoptions)
resp = r['data']
resp['c'] = resp.apply(lambda x: result(x['a'],x['b']),axis=1)
test= r['data'].copy()
test['c'] = test.apply(lambda x: result(x['a'],x['b']),axis=1)
test
```